# Customizing tooltip with CSS

Tags: python, css, pyqt

While customizing QToolTip using:

```
app.setStyleSheet("QToolTip {
font-size:9pt;
color:white; padding:2px;
border-width:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-radius:20px;
background-color: black;
border: 1px solid white;}");
```

the white border-outline is properly rounded with `border-radius:20px;`.
But the QToolTip main frame still has the sharp edges.

How to round the entire QToolTip frame and not just the white frame outline border?

Here is the image showing the problem:

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` like below.

```
 app.setStyleSheet("QToolTip {
  font-size:9pt;
  color:white; padding:2px;
  border-width:2px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-radius:20px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  overflow:hidden;}");
```

Comment: Ops, looks like it is not working. QT complains `Unknown property overflow`

Comment: overflow:hidden is CSS but cannot be used in Qt, has the proposed solution been tested?